# Arrow diagram from indesign

Tags: tikz-pgf

I found following diagram highlighted with a yellow circle around it in Math ebooks which is created by Adobe Indesign.

Could someone create it by using `Tikz`?
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows,chains}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can start with

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols, fit, shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[signal,fill=gray!30, signal to=east, label=left:lente, label=right:rapide] (A) {$(\ln n)^\gamma\quad n^\alpha\quad n^\beta\quad a^n\quad b^n\quad n!$};

\node[fit=(A), ellipse, draw, thick, yellow!80!gray] (F) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In fact there is no cercle in the book i just add it to point diagram but it's cool with cercle  Thank you